# Perl pattern extraction from file

Tags: perl

I have a text file like :

```
Name : first  
File name : first_1  
Year : 12  
etc  
etc  
etc  
T1 : this is t1  
T2 : this is t2  
T3 : this is t3  
Conclusion : Success  
Name : first  
File name : first_2   
Year : 13  
etc  
etc  
etc  
T1 : this is t1  
T2 : this is t2  
T3 : this is t3  
Conclusion : Success 
Name : second  
File name : second_1  
Year : 12  
etc  
etc  
etc  
T1 : this is t1  
T2 : this is t2  
T3 : this is t3  
Conclusion : Failure  
Name : first  
File name : first_3  
Year : 12  
etc  
etc  
etc  
T1 : this is t1  
T2 : this is t2  
T3 : this is t3  
Conclusion : Success
```

## and so on.....

I need a perl script which gives me the following output:

```
Naming  File_name  Year  Conclusion  Reason  
first   first_1    12    Success     this is t1, this is t2, this is t3    
first   first_2    13    Success     this is t1, this is t2, this is t3   
second  second_1   12    Failure     this is t1, this is t2, this is t3  
first   first_3    12    Success     this is t1, this is t2, this is t3
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) SO is not a write-some-code-for-me site. You'll have to try for yourself and when you're stuck somewhere then state your problem here and you'll get help.

Comment: @dgw so sorry for that, I tried the following way:

Comment: @dgw so sorry for that, I tried the following way:
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   my $readLine;
   my $string;

    open (TEST_READ, "read.txt") || die "Can't open read.txt, $!";
    open (TEST_WRITE, ">write.txt") || die "Can't create write.txt,$!";


    while($readLine = <TEST_READ>)
    {
 
 if($readLine =~ m/Name :(.*)/ or $readLine =~ m/File name :(.*)/ or $readLine =~ m/Year :(.*)/ or $readLine =~ m/Conclusion :(.*)/)
 {
  $string = $1;
  $string =~ s/^\s+//;
  $string =~ s/\s+$//;
  print TEST_WRITE $string;
  print TEST_WRITE "\n";
 }
}


close TEST_READ;
close TEST_WRITE;

Comment: @ShaggyShaggy: Nobody can read that.  Please edit your question and put the code in there.  Make sure it's marked as code markup by being indented 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following does what you need. It reads the file to parse from STDIN. Could be any other array of lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $Naming = "";
my $File_name = "";
my $Year = "";
my @Reason = ();
my $Conclusion = "";

print "Naming\tFile_name\tYear\tConclusion\tReason\n";
while (my $line = <STDIN>) {
  $line =~ /Conclusion : (\w+)/ and do {
    $Conclusion = $1;

    print "$Naming\t$File_name\t$Year\t$Conclusion\t" . join(", ",@Reason) . "\n";
    $Naming = "";
    $File_name = "";
    $Year = "";
    @Reason = ();
    $Conclusion = "";
  };

  $line =~ /Name : (.*)/ and $Naming = $1;
  $line =~ /File name : (.*)/ and $File_name = $1;
  $line =~ /Year : (\d+)/ and $Year = $1;
  $line =~ /T\d : (.*)/ and push(@Reason,$1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what you are having problems with. Splitting the stream into records? This will do the trick:

```
my @buf;
while (<>) {
   if (@buf && /^Name :/) {
      process_record(@buf);
      @buf = ();
   }

   push @buf, $_;
}

process_record(@buf) if @buf;
```